# Laravel many to many model relationship

Tags: model-view-controller, database-design, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I have a table called jobs and another table called job_questions - a job can have five screening questions. Table job_questions is a type of lookup table but with some additional data as follows:

```
job_questions
-------------
job_id  int
question_id int 
question  varchar
expected_answer enum ('y',  'n')

job_id | question_id | question               | expected_answer
--------------------------------------------------------------
   1   |      1      | Do you have experience |     Y
```

There is no table called questions - question_id merely refers to question numbers on a form (1-5) How would you map such a model in laravel since you dont normally have a many to many model class in laravel? Do i create a model class for the lookup table, otherwise I how would i pull the additional information it contains?

Answer (score 0):

If one question can be in multiple jobs, you indeed have a many to many relationship.

You're gonna need one table for jobs and one table for questions to represent the data. To actually make a relationship, you're gonna need a pivot table. Basically it's gonna have a `job_id` and a `question_id`, so if job `3` has questions `1`, `2` and `3`, there will be three rows in this table with the job_id `3` and the three question_id.

You don't need a model for this pivot table, just a model for the two actual data.

In your models, the relationship functions don't change much. Both have the `many` word: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job', 'pivot_table_name', 'question_id_column', 'job_id_column')`. You also may put this method in the other model so you can query the relationships both ways, question's jobs and job's questions. Parameters 2 and on to the belongsToMany are optional but you'll probably need at least the second to set the pivot table name.

Docs to this is here:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many
and
 http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: the question is user entered string and so each question is unique to each job. Hence its not a clear cut many to many relation ship otherwise I would have created a questions table. To make it clearer question id is really just the question number (1-5) the primary key of the job_questions table is a compound primary key made up of the job_id and question_number. I could just add five questions to the jobs table and get rid of the job_questions table altogether 5 x  i.e q1_question, q1_expected_answer; q2_question, q2_expected_answer. job_questions allows more flexibility to have more questio

Comment: I would say its a 1:N relationship, one job can have many questions; one question only belongs to one job.

Comment: Then it's much simpler. On the job model you make a function with: `hasMany('App\Question')`. On the question you use `belongsTo('App\Job')`